# Google Directory API return access_denied when call groups().list().execute()

Tags: google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk

- Library : google-api-services-admin-directory_v1-rev11-1.16.0-rc.jar
- API Console : Service Account
- Domain 3rd party OAuth Client Access Setting
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user

Getting users list is work, but groups list return error (access_denied)

**Source**

```
scopeList.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER);
scopeList.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP);
scopeList.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP_MEMBER);

credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
    .setServiceAccountId("xxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
    .setServiceAccountScopes(scopeList)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File("xxxxx-privatekey.p12"))
    .setServiceAccountUser("admin@test.com")
    .build();

Directory admin = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
    .setApplicationName("Test")
    .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();


admin.users().list().setDomain("test.com").execute();
admin.groups().list().setDomain("test.com").execute();
```

**Error**

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "access_denied"
}
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:332)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:269)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:454)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:215)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:854)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Is the Service Account granted access for the groups API scope? (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly). See the [Google Drive docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account) for details on how to do this)
- Is the ServiceAccountUser a super administrator or is he a delegated admin that has been granted rights to manage groups via API?

Comment: ServiceAccountUser is super administrator, and Service Account have granted access scopse for group. (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group)

Comment: It's strange that users().list() is succeeded, but groups.list() is failed.

Comment: I found the problem. Below line makes trouble.
scopeList.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP_MEMBER);

Comment: @Moongle how did you grant access scopes for user and groups to your Service Account? I couldn't find where I can do it. I use the same code but always receive either "error" : "access_denied" or   "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not Authorized to access this resource/api" ...

Comment: @dmitry747 please post a new question for this.

Comment: @Jay Lee created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568716/google-directory-api-returns-not-authorized-when-call-users-list-execute