# Google Directory API returns Not Authorized when call users().list().execute()

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk

I need to read the list of users (and groups) from my google domain.

So I went to my Google APIs Console and enabled **Admin SDK** and created a **Service Account** to call Google APIs. I use the following google libraries

- google-api-services-admin-directory_v1-rev11-1.16.0-rc.jar
- google-api-client-1.16.0-rc.jar

My code is

```
     /*
     * Global instance of the JSON factory.
     */
    final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
     /*
      Global instance of the HTTP transport.
     */
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        Collection<String> scopeList = new ArrayList<>();
        scopeList.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER);
        scopeList.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP);
        scopeList.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP_MEMBER);

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId("nnnnnn@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                .setServiceAccountScopes(scopeList)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("/Path/To/KeyFile/nnnnn-privatekey.p12"))
//                .setServiceAccountUser("admin@mydomain.org")
                .build();

        Directory admin = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName("Test")
                .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();


        Users users = admin.users().list().setDomain("mydomain.org").execute();
```

And I receive this on the last line

**Error**

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1045)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
```

If I uncomment the commented line (`.setServiceAccountUser("admin@mydomain.org")`) then I get a different error

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "access_denied"
}
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:269)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:858)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
```

My account (admin@mydomain.org) is a **super administrator**. I suspect the Service Account needs to be granted access for the **users API scope**. But **I can not find where I can grant this access**. I have a classic UI mode of my Google CPanel. And I don't have "Manage client API access" page in the Advanced tools.

[image: Advanced tools]

Also I'm not sure what I should use as an Application Name at `.setApplicationName("Test")`.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

you can go to "security" settings in the admin console (admin.google.com/AdminHome?chromeless=1&pli=1#SecuritySettings:); then click on advance settings > Manage third party OAuth Client access. After this map your client id(generated from appconsole code.google.com/apis/console under API access for oath2) and "One or More API Scopes". Use comma separated scopes as mentioned there. For google directory you can use https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user

Hope after this it works :)

Comment: I've got the classic admin console. The pages are on other locations.

Comment: i am using a trial account and not getting this option, just says 'Manage OAuth Client access'. is it because of the trial or is there some configuration required

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem, and was stucked on [this sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2?hl=FR#Service_accounts)

What helped me :
1/ I did not [Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account), as suggested by Jay Lee. But after that, I still had the problem.
2/ Then, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706339/received-error-not-authorized-to-access-this-resource-api-when-trying-to-use-g/18706858#18706858), the call to setServiceAccountUser(yourAdminAccount@yourDomain.com) is mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

Google Directory API works with Compute Engine default service account, you do not need to setup Google Drive domain-wide. The only thing: you have to set serviceAccountUser, which is not supported in JSON based credentials. So you can

- use P12 keys
- user JSON credentials with workaround:

make credential copy:

```
import static com.google.api.client.googleapis.util.Utils.getDefaultJsonFactory;
import static com.google.api.client.googleapis.util.Utils.getDefaultTransport;

private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "AnyAppName";

private final List<String> SCOPES = ImmutableList.of(
        DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP_MEMBER, DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER, DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP);

private Directory service;

@PostConstruct
void init() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    GoogleCredential credential;
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("./config/client_secret.json")) {
        credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(is);
    }
    GoogleCredential credentialWithUser = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(getDefaultTransport())
            .setJsonFactory(getDefaultJsonFactory())
            .setServiceAccountUser("admin@yourdomain.ru")  // <--- mail of domain's admin
            .setServiceAccountId(credential.getServiceAccountId())
            .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(credential.getServiceAccountPrivateKey())
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyId(credential.getServiceAccountPrivateKeyId())
            .setTokenServerEncodedUrl(credential.getTokenServerEncodedUrl()).build();

    service = new Directory.Builder(getDefaultTransport(), getDefaultJsonFactory(), credentialWithUser).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
}

 public void members() throws IOException {
    Members members = service.members().list("groupName@yourdomain.ru").execute();
    System.out.println(members);
 }
```

For my [trial G Suite account](https://gsuite.google.com/intl/en/products/) it works!

Answer (score 1):

You can grant the service account access to certain scopes in the Control Panel as explained in the [Google Drive domain-wide documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account). Just use Admin SDK scopes instead.

The application name is used in the User-Agent header of requests and so is not overly important, just use your apps name and maybe version.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can not find this "Manage third party OAuth Client access." item in the Advanced tools in my Control Panel as described in the Google Drive doc. Probably I need to enable it somehow?

Comment: See instructions at: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=162106. It sounds like you may have the new admin console enabled.

Comment: I couldn't find this "Manage client API access" page. I added a picture of my Advanced tools. Probably I need to enable something?

Comment: What edition of Google Apps are you using? (EDU, Business, Free/Standard)?

Comment: I'm using Google Apps Partner Edition

Comment: According to: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites under "Setup the basics", GAfP is not a supported edtion. You could try accessing the API directly as a super admin using standard OAuth 2.0 but I do not believe Service Accounts are an option for you.

Comment: I moved to the old gdata API. That API seems doing what I need to.