# Received error "Not Authorized to access this resource/api" when trying to use Google Directory API and Service Account Authentication

Tags: python, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

I'm really struggling with trying to use Service Account authentication to use the Google Directory API (Admin SDK).

Using client based three legged OAuth this works (tested here - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/insert) but there's a problem with the permission delegation to the service account I am using. Under the Google Apps administration, I enabled using APIs and added the service account to the list of allowed OAuth clients as instructed.

Here is the code:

```
import httplib2
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    '<KEY>@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
    '<KEY DATA>',
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member'
)
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build("admin", "directory_v1", http=http)
groups = service.groups()
g = groups.get(groupKey="<GROUP NAME>").execute()
```

Eventually, I get the following error:

```
apiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/<GROUP NAME>?alt=json returned "Not Authorized to access this resource/api">
```

I tried using the following API as well:

```
service = build("groupssettings", "v1", http=http)
```

But this returns an error as well - "Backend Error".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Even though you're using a Service Account you still need to act on behalf of a Google Apps user in the instance that has the proper admin permissions. Try doing:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
  '<KEY>@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
  '<KEY DATA>',
  scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member',
  sub='super-admin@yourdomain.com'
)
```

where super-admin@yourdomain.com is a super administrator in your Google Apps account.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! How did you know this solution? I knew this type of solution was the one I was looking for but I couldn't find the relevant docs.

Comment: This sub='super-admin@yourdomain.com' make it works !

Comment: This process is now documented at: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

Comment: Do we still use 'super-admin@yourdomain.com' as serviceAccountUser?? It seems like only 'admin@yourdomain.com' is legitimate.

Comment: but what does this mean? Even in 2017 I can't figure this out: I just want to know *my* organizations, why does this require a domain admin email? How does one get this information without that kind of email address?

Comment: Using the `google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials` API, this is:

`creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_json, scopes=scopes, subject="super-admin@yourdomain.com")`
```