# Accessing a Google Domain's Google Groups from a service account - Keep getting 403 unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-groups-api, google-groups-settings

I'm trying to get a list of groups for a domain in Google Api (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list).

I'm using "domain wide delegation", and have a service account from which the web app makes all its requests to Google.
The admin-sdk requires the requesting user to be an administrator, so i'm impersonating a admin user on the given domain.

This works fine with (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get), but when I'm trying to use the group api, it fails like this:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
 }
}
```

I have checked the the permissions from the domain administrator have been delegated to the service account. And I have also checked that i can access the list of groups, while being logged in as the domain administrator.

Any help or hints is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add the scope for reading groups.

Comment: This led me to checking the scopes once again. It was set up correctly on the domain administrator account, and the api was enabled on the service account. But I then realized that at some point, I also added the scopes when creating the JWT token. And this indeed solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you properly followed the steps here in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) including this steps on how to [Instantiate an Admin SDK Directory service object](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#instantiate_an_admin_sdk_directory_service_object).

It is important because this one shows you how to make API requests using OAuth 2.0 and your service account's credentials to perform Google Apps Domain-wide delegation.

For more information, check these related SO questions:

- [Google_Service_Directory - (403) Not Authorized to access this resource/api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409201/google-service-directory-403-not-authorized-to-access-this-resource-api)
- [Received error “Not Authorized to access this resource/api” when trying to use Google Directory API and Service Account Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706339/received-error-not-authorized-to-access-this-resource-api-when-trying-to-use-g)

Comment: Thank you, i did go back and tried to check the setup again, but since it already worked with the directory/user, i knew the setup was already working. Only not for the directory/group api.